# TRUE Formula for a number of different columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Question to see if someone can help me.  I have twelve columns and need them all to be equal, so for example if A3 is "S1", and B3 is "S1" and C3 is "S1", etc. through column J3 (which is S1), I am looking for a formula that can give me a TRUE/FALSE that all of these cells are "S1". So if it was just A3 and B3 I would just use (=A3=B3) and it would answer "TRUE". But I need to test to make sure all of the Columns are S1, so I need a "TRUE" formula for all of these cells.

Hopefully this question is clear - thanks so much for anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNTIF:

`=COUNTIF(A1:L1,B1)=COUNTA(A1:L1)`

This will give you TRUE only if all that cells has the same value.
(B1 is just a value from the range,  it can be any cell of that (our even you can refer to an external value to check whether each cell is equal to that value))

(COUNTA just counts all the cells in the range to avoid mistakes if you change the name but forget to change the number)

Comment: Suggestion: change S1 to A1.  The S1 in the question is an arbitrary example, but the test is that all of the cells are the same.  So you're really testing whatever is in any selected cell in the range rather than a specific value, or a value stored in a cell outside the range.